# Securing Asp.NET Core Uppy.js Endpoint

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, tus, uppy

I'm using [Uppy.io](https://uppy.io/) as client side tus.io implementation in my ASP.NET MVC web application.

And [tusdotnet](https://github.com/tusdotnet/tusdotnet) v2.0.0 as server side in ASP.NET Core Web API.

It works fine all the way but how can we limit the file uploads only to authenticated users?

Here is the code snippet from my Razor page:

```
var uppy = new Uppy.Core({ debug: true, autoProceed: false });


var uppy = new Uppy.Core(
    {
        debug: true
        , autoProceed: false
        , allowMultipleUploads: true
        , restrictions: {
            maxFileSize: 157286400,
            allowedFileTypes: ['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation', 'application/zip']
        }
    }
);

uppy.use(Uppy.Dashboard, {
    trigger: '.UppyModalOpenerBtn',
    inline: true,
    target: '.DashboardContainer'
});
uppy.use(Uppy.Tus10, { endpoint: '@ViewBag.APIURL' });
uppy.run();
```

Code snippet from .NET Core project in Configure method of Startup.cs:

```
app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseTus(context => new DefaultTusConfiguration
        {
            UrlPath = "/files",
            Store = new TusDiskStore(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, @"uploads\tusio")),
            OnUploadCompleteAsync = async (fileId, store, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                //var file = await (store as ITusReadableStore)
                //    .GetFileAsync(fileId, cancellationToken);
                //return fileId;
            }
        });
```

Everything works fine but I don't want WebAPI to save files sent by anonymous users.

Any solution or workaround would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

**GitHub issue:** 
https://github.com/tusdotnet/tusdotnet/issues/76

Comment: require authorization for GetFileAsync() method?

Comment: @yob No. I comment out the extra code from `OnUploadCompleteAsync` callback method. The problem is file gets uploaded no matter who sends the file to the server. I don't want anyone to send the file and let server save it.

Comment: this? -> https://github.com/tusdotnet/tusdotnet/wiki/OnAuthorizeAsync-event

Comment: thank you @yob. You may answer the question I'll accept. Please add this event is not available in v2.0.0. I updated to v2.2.2 to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @yob, you can secure the "/files" endpoint with the OnAuthorizeAsync event:

```
app.UseTus(httpContext => new DefaultTusConfiguration{
    ...
    Events = new Events 
    {
        OnAuthorizeAsync = eventContext => 
        {
            if (!eventContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
            {
                eventContext.FailRequest(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
});
```